# Consulta onde um conjunto não pode se repetir

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server-2012

Olá! Tenho o seguinte problema:

Possuo uma tabela com os seguintes campos:

```
Tabela código:

ID |  Cod01 | Cod02

1     10         1010
2     10         1010
```

A tabela acima representa a forma correta de como as informações devem ser armazenadas, ou seja, para o Cod01 devo ter sempre o Cod02. O problema é que caso ocorra dos dados serem salvos de forma incorreta, como ficaria a consulta caso o Cod01 possuir um valor diferente no Cod02? Exemplo:

```
Tabela código:

ID |  Cod01 | Cod02

1     10         1010
2     10         1010

3     20         2020
4     20         2020
5     30         3030
6     30         3030
7     10         1011
```

No caso acima gostaria de consultar a os registros onde há divergências entre o Cod01 e o Cod02

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que entendi do seu problema, é que sempre a coluna Cod02 é para ser o mesmo valor da coluna Cod01, porém esse registro pode ser cadastrado erroneamente o que causaria erro/falha na aplicação.
Nesse caso você pode apenas concatenar os valores da coluna Cod01 e comparar com a coluna Cod02, por ex:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
     SELECT
        COD01, 
        COD02, 
        CASE WHEN (COD01 || COD01 <> COD02) THEN 'DIFERENTE' ELSE NULL END AS ISDIFERENTE 
     FROM TABELA_CODIGO
) AS DADOS
WHERE DADOS.ISDIFERENTE IS NOT NULL
```

Com essa sql, a coluna ISDIFERENTE vai concatenar o valor da coluna Cod01 duas vezes e comparar com a Cod02, e caso seja diferente ele retorna um texto 'Diferente'.
Espero ter ajudado.